# Add new unique markers to existing set of markers (Google Maps)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google maps that retrieves the marker's info (LatLng etc..) from a PHP script via JSON. There is a Google Maps listener that removes all existing markers, retrieves the markers on `bounds_changed` and adds them to the map.

**Problem:** Due to a large number of markers being drawn on the map, every time the user changes the map bounds (drag, zoom...), *ALL* the markers gets removed, retrieved and added again, cause quite a delay mainly due to the drawing of new markers (i think). Many times, the user just change the bounds by just a little, resulting in a re-addition of maybe 75% of the markers.

To speed this up, I decided that on `bounds_changed` event, the map should only clear the markers that are now bound of the map bounds, and download and add the new markers that are now within the map bounds. How can this be done?

**Additional Info:** I do have an array `markers[]` where all newly created markers are `pushed` into

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at the [MarkerManager Library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/reference.html)

This should help you out and you will avoid rolling your own solution.

Comment: the MarkerManager library is the correct way if you decide to load all your markers upfront.


If you are instead querying your server (via ajax) then you will instead need to do a hash approach where you keep a collection of the markers that are already on the map and then loop though and remove the ones that are no longer needed (ie remove the ones that are not in the new query that returned from the server) and add the ones that aren't already on the map (so you don't have duplicate markers)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the bounds_changed event fires continuously when the user is panning the map. You should do something like this in the event handler:

```
if(reloadTimer){
  clearTimeout(reloadTimer);
}
reloadTimer = setTimeout(function(){
  // fetch new data
}, 400);
```

Second, if you can minimize the number of requests by caching some of the data on the client, the user interface will probably be much more responsive. You could cache quite a large number of markers on the client and still maintain a great performance. Keep in mind that the markers should be removed from the map if they're outside the visible bounds as they will be bad for performance.

You can cache the data on the client in several ways, mostly dependent on your users and how they use your application. The quickest way to implement caching would be to transfer all the data from the server in one request, and create a datastructure in javascript which the map will get the markers from. This datastructure would exist in the page scope and make the map operations faster. The server response may also be cached in the browser, if you can afford to set the expiration headers to a certain amount of time.

If your users return to you application, you could save the datastructure to localStorage or sessionStorage, using HTML5. Maybe you could update the data regularly when the user is idling on your page.

More on local storege: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

*PS!* You should also follow skarE's advice on using the idle event instead of the bounds_changed.

*PPS!* When it comes to displaying the markers in the map, MarkerManager is a good idea. I also recommend  MarkerClusterer ( http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html ) if you want to combine markers in areas with high marker density into groups of clusters.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the caching? I'm not of familiar with caching markers, thanks!

Comment: Instead of bounds_changes, listen to the 'idle' event.